# Syntax error in binary search tree in ocaml

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

```
type (ty1,ty2) btree = Empty
  | Node of (ty1,ty2) * (ty1,ty2) btree * (ty1,ty2) btree;;
```

Here is my code to write a constructor. write down OCaml expressions of type `(ty1,ty2) tree`, for suitable types `ty1` and `ty2`, that represent trees of the kind we are interested in.

```
When I run that 
7 | type (ty1,ty2) btree = Empty
          ^^^
Error: Syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type variables need to be prefixed with an apostrophe, `'`, to distinguish them from concrete types.

The syntax for the first parameter of `Node` is also not valid. I assume you mean for it to be a tuple:

```
type ('ty1, 'ty2) btree = Empty
  | Node of ('ty1 * 'ty2) * ('ty1, 'ty2) btree * ('ty1, 'ty2) btree;;
```